# Fixed sorting order of hosts in inventory_hostname groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using AWX with the combination of CMDB inventory and many groups are defined there . i.e. from set_A to set_Z and blah blah blah

I am calling many groups in my Playbook i.e. 'set_A, set_B, set_C, set_D' and hosts exist in each group.

host9 is in set_C inventory group
host1 and 3 is in set_B inventory group
host7 is in set_A inventory group

When I am calling below it's giving me bunch of warning messages but it's doing the Job.

```
"[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: inventory_hostname in groups[
"{{item}}" ]

My syntax is:
    inventory_hostname in groups[ "{{item}}" ] 
        with_items:
          - 'set_A'
          - 'set_B'
          - 'set_C'
          - 'set_D'
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Also on each run playbook is randomizing sorting order each time. i.e. picking up hosts in set_B first then set_A then set_C.

What I want is that: Group order must be strictly followed if hosts exist:

- If hosts exist in set_A then it **MUST run first**, then hosts in set_B then hosts in set_C and so on and so forth. For some reason sorting order is shuffling each time.

Is there a way that sorting order can be fixed/ or same each time? host sorting order is not important but the group sorting order is.